# Import multiple Properties returns an error

Tags: android, properties, import, greendao

I'm currently working on an android project, using greenDAO as ORM, and I need to make multiple requests on different tables of my database. But when I try to import multiple Properties (useful for the `.where()` queries) I got this error :

```
The import psa_gt.dao.quizz_categoriesDao.Properties collides with another import statement
```

My import :

```
import package.dao.quizz_questionsDao.Properties;
import package.dao.quizz_categoriesDao.Properties;
```

My queries (the second returns this error : `"Quizz_categories_id_quizz cannot be resolved or is not a field"`) :

```
List<quizz_questions> list_questions = daoquestions.queryBuilder().where(Properties.Quizz_questions_id_quizz.eq(value)).list();
List<quizz_categories> list_categories = daocategories.queryBuilder().where(Properties.Quizz_categories_id_quizz.eq(value)).list();
```

Hope you can help me with that.

(Sorry for my bad English but there is no French support for greenDAO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties used in the code is ambiguous since compiler doesn't know whether to resolve it to package dao.quizz_questionsDao or dao.quizz_categoriesDao

**Solution**:
Remove the imports.
And in code use fully qualified class name. i.e.

List list_questions = daoquestions.queryBuilder().where(**dao.quizz_questionsDao.Properties**.Quizz_questions_id_quizz.eq(value)).list(); List list_categories = daocategories.queryBuilder().where(**dao.quizz_categoriesDao.Properties**.Quizz_categories_id_quizz.eq(value)).list();